# Problema con ODBC al intentar conectar a la base de datos de SAGE 100

Tags: c#, odbc

Tengo un problema al conectar a la base de datos de Sage mediante ODBC, ya que la DB se encuentra en un servidor. Cuando pruebo la conexión desde el servidor todo esta OK, pero desde local me arroja estos problemas:

> ERROR [S1000] [Simba][SimbaEngine ODBC Driver][DRM File Library]Mauvaise version de dossier !
> ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] Error de SQLSetConnectAttr del controlador
> ERROR [01S00] [Simba][SimbaEngine ODBC Driver]Invalid connection string attribute.
> ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] El controlador no admite una versión de ODBC distinta de la que la necesita la aplicación (vea SQLSetEnvAttr).

Mi código:

```
namespace TestOdbc
{
    class ConnectToDatabase
    {
        public ConnectToDatabase()
        {
            OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.Add("Driver", "{SQL Server}");
            builder.Add("UID", "<Admin>");
            builder.Add("PWD", " ");
            builder.Add("DSN", "ONE_DB");
            Conenct(builder.ConnectionString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void Conenct(string conection)
        {
            using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(conection))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("connected!!!!!!---------------------------");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ODBC Connection test failed!!!!");
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                    conn.Close();
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("ODBC Connection test PASSED!");
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que hay 2 versiones de OBDC una es para 32 bits y la otra para 64bits.

Si tu aplicación esta en 32 bits crea una ODBC para 32 bits y lo mismo para 64Bits.

Si utilizas la pestaña DSN de usuario solamente el usuario que creo esa ODBC podrá verla, utiliza mejor la pestaña DSN de sistema para generar la ODBC.

Normalmente el error  "El controlador no admite una versión de ODBC distinta de la que la necesita la aplicación" si haces una app de 64bits tienes que utilizar un ODBC de 64Bits